# Kalman Filter (Optimal Interpolation) for time series prediction

Tags: kalman-filter

I am coding up a Kalman Filter (KF) algorithm where the data are the daily returns of a single stock. I have arrived at an issue when I try to update the 'analysis' (this is the forecast plus the Kalman gain multiplied by the difference between the observation and forecast).

$x^a_{t + 1} = x^f_{t + 1} + K_{t + 1}(y_{t + 1} - x^f_{t + 1})$

My issue is the covariance matrix is $n \times n$ dimensional representing the covariance of returns across all my trading days and both the forecast and observation are scalars, meaning that the Kalman Gain, $K$ is also $n \times n$.

Should I just use the variance of returns (diagonal entries of covariance matrix) rather than the entire matrix? My concern with this is that we ignore the covariance of returns between time points.